# Rspec be_valid fails on a valid test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm learning TDD with Rails 4 and rspec. I've made some test cases for my user model to check the password lengths. I have two tests so far that checks whether a user input a password that was too short and one where the password is between 6 - 10 characters.

So far, the "password is too short" test passes:

```
it "validation says password too short if password is less than 6 characters" do
  short_password = User.create(email: "tester@gmail.com", password: "12345")
  expect(short_password).not_to be_valid
end
```

However, on the test where I do have a valid password, it fails:

```
it "validation allows passwords larger than 6 and less than 10" do
  good_password = User.create(email: "tester2@gmail.com", password: "blahblah")
  expect(good_password).to be_valid
end
```

And I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(good_password).to be_valid
   expected #<User id: 1, email: "tester2@gmail.com", 
   created_at: "2014-06-21 02:43:42", updated_at: "2014-06-21 02:43:42",
   password_digest: nil, password: nil, password_hash: "$2a$10$7u0xdDEcc6KJcAi32LBW7uzV9n7xYbfOhZWdcOnU5Cdm...",
   password_salt: "$2a$10$7u0xdDEcc6KJcAi32LBW7u"> to be valid, 
   but got errors: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's my model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pets, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets, :allow_destroy => true
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
  uniqueness: true

  validates :password, presence: true, :length => 6..10, :confirmation => true

  #callbacks
  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  #method to authenticate the user and password
  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  #method to encrypt password
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  #clears password
  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end
end
```

I'm confused on why the password is nil when I create the test object.

Comment: Your model must have some callbacks affecting the way password is calculated. This shows from the `password_hash` and `password_salt` being populated. Can you show your model code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is the `password` field is not mass assignable. That is why `password` is nil in the output message.

Try this instead:

```
it "validation allows passwords larger than 6 and less than 10" do
  good_password = User.create(email: "tester2@gmail.com")
  good_password.password = "blahblah"
  expect(good_password).to be_valid
end
```

Note that your first test is passing accidentally - it has the same problem as the second test (password isn't being assigned). This means you aren't actually testing that the password is rejected when less than 6 characters atm.

See [this article on mass assignment](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695) for more details.

EDIT: Leo Correa's comment may suggest this may not be the case for you. Posting your model code would help...

Comment: 5 years on... Mass assignment was moved into the controller layer in Rails 4. Nothing (by default) should prevent assignation of any field on the model.

Answer (score 2):

You have a password presence requirement on your model, but then you have an `after_save` hook that nilifies the password and puts the record into an invalid state. The first test passes because your records are always being put into an invalid state by the `after_save` hook. You need to rethink how you're handling password storage; once you resolve that, here are some code samples to help give you some ways to test this:

```rb
# Set up a :user factory in spec/factories.rb; it should look something like:
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "tester+#{n}@gmail.com" }
    password         { SecureRandom.hex(6) }
  end
end 

# In your spec:
let(:user) { create :user, password: password }

context 'password' do
  context 'length < 6' do
    let(:password) { '12345' } 


    it { expect(user).not_to be_valid }
    it { user.errors.message[:password]).to include('something') }
  end 

  context 'length >= 6' do
    context 'length < 10' do
      let(:password) { 'blahblah' }

      it { expect(user).to be_valid }
    end

    context 'length >= 10' do
      let(:password) { 'blahblahblah' }

      it { expect(user).not_to be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use [shoulda matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers):

```
it { should_not allow_value('12345').for(:password) }
it { should allow_value('12345blah').for(:password) }
```